# Why does this default route redirect?

Tags: python, api, redirect, curl, flask

While testing the API functionality with curl, i tried sending a post data to the route below. while watching the debug, the views rather responded to a 301 redirect preventing to grab the needed data. what am i doing wrong?

here is my current views.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)




@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/api/user/login/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'Got request for login'
    print args
    print kwargs
    print request.args
    print request.args.get("username")
    print request.values.get("username")
    print request.method

    response = {'username': 'Erik'}

    dict = request.args
    for key in dict:
        print 'form key ' + dict[key]

    # return jsonify(response)
    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Calling the following code,

```
curl -d "username=Flash" http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/user/login
```

initiates a redirection

```
/home/user/fab/bin/python2.7 /home/user/PycharmProjects/myelm/server.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2017 23:04:25] "POST /api/user/login HTTP/1.1" 301 -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#variable-rules) about this behavior:

> Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior
>   Flask’s URL rules are based on Werkzeug’s routing module. The idea behind that module is to ensure beautiful and unique URLs based on precedents laid down by Apache and earlier HTTP servers.
>
> Take these two rules:
>
> ```
> @app.route('/projects/')
> def projects():
>     return 'The project page'
>
> @app.route('/about')
> def about():
>     return 'The about page'
> ```
>
> Though they look rather similar, they differ in their use of the trailing slash in the URL definition. In the first case, the canonical URL for the projects endpoint has a trailing slash. In that sense, it is similar to a folder on a filesystem. Accessing it without a trailing slash will cause Flask to redirect to the canonical URL with the trailing slash.
>
> In the second case, however, the URL is defined without a trailing slash, rather like the pathname of a file on UNIX-like systems. Accessing the URL with a trailing slash will produce a 404 “Not Found” error.
>
> This behavior allows relative URLs to continue working even if the trailing slash is omitted, consistent with how Apache and other servers work. Also, the URLs will stay unique, which helps search engines avoid indexing the same page twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, that solved the issue. I have remove the trailing slash to get the needed response.